# Анимация с помощью свойства transition в CSS

Tags: css

У меня такая проблема. Вот сейчас делаю учебный проект и для кнопки я задал анимация (плавный переход с помощью transition) но почему-то после подгрузки (иными словами после рендеринга) появляется анимация для всех кнопок. Как сделать так, чтобы анимация была только во время наведения курсором а не во время рендеринга страницы?

Comment: у меня тоже проблема - сможешь описать как её решить ?

Comment: @Ibrahim Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное что-то типа такого

```
.className{
    transition: color .3s ease;
    color: green;
}
.className:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Да, но почему-то после перезагрузки страницы, анимация происходят для всех элементов. Можно сделать, чтобы после перезагрузки страницы, анимация на элементы не прикручивалась?

Comment: Покажите код, пожалуйста

Comment: @Ibrahim Для каждой кнопки присвойте свой класс